# Javascript timestamp is far in the future

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to return a timestamp of the current date. I use this JavaScript commands:

```js
var date = Date.now();
var par = document.getElementById("testdate");
par.innerHTML = date;
```

```html
<p id="testdate"></p>
```

This returns e.g. the following timestamp: 1529489842210

But when I check the timestamp, I get the following date: 08/08/50437 @ 5:30pm (UTC)

Which is definitely not the current date^^ Or I have been sleeping way too long ;)

Comment: JavaScript shows in milliseconds. You have to convert it to seconds in PHP.

Comment: its is millisecond

Comment: Ohhhh, so this is not a unix timestamp?^^

Comment: @JonasLöffel - It's similar, just the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch and using idealized days (they're exactly 86400000ms long, no leap seconds or similar). (I think "Unix timestamp" can mean either seconds or milliseconds since The Epoch nowadays, but the exact terminology isn't all that important here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript shows in milliseconds elapsed since epoch. You have to convert it to seconds in PHP. Use:

```
strtotime($date/1000);
```

Also, in JavaScript, you can use `new Date()`:

[image: preview]

Shows me the right time:

```
» new Date(1529489842210)
« Wed Jun 20 2018 11:17:22 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Comment: Done :) unfortunately I cant upvote your answer due to my reportation is not hight enough

Comment: @JonasLöffel Hey that's totally fine. Thanks for the accept. Hope you got the answer you are looking for... `:D`

Comment: @JonasLöffel Guess you can vote up now. Congrats on the new privilege... `:D`